# copying a file in c++ with variable directories

Tags: c++, string, directory, copy, cin

Basically I'm trying to copy a file from one place to another but I want the user to be able to change were to because its for a steam game and everyone has a diffident username.

```
system("copy GameMenu.res C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\"login"\\counter-strike source\\cstrike\\resource\\GameMenu.res");
```

In this line where it says "login" I want for people to be able to type their username and so it is still a part of the directory or whatever the thing is called. Please help me.

here is the code here is the whole code so you can see what's wrong with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
int main ()
{
using namespace std;

string login;
int drive;

cout << "What is your steam login??" << endl;

cin >> login;

system("timeout 2");

system("cls");

cout << "Your files are being copied " << login << "." << endl;

system("copy GameMenu.res C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\"login"\\counter-strike source\\cstrike\\resource\\GameMenu.res");

system("pause");

system("cls");

system("timeout 1");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You also need to look at enclosing the copy destination in `"`, since it has spaces.

Comment: Plus, you make assumption on where they have steam installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepare your String using concatenation for your login name problem and then convert it to `const char *`:

```
string str = "copy GameMenu.res \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\" + login + "\\counter-strike source\\cstrike\\resource\\GameMenu.res\"";
const char * c = str.c_str();

system(c);
```

Also as crashmstr mentioned in the comments, as you have spaces in your path you could have problems, so consider following his advice.

Comment: I tried that but its not compiling and i get this error C:\Users\Seb\Documents\template.cpp cannot convert `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to `const char*' for argument `1' to `int system(const char*)'

Comment: @user1308252 and if you prepare your `const char *` before like my updated answer?

Comment: So now how would I put this into the whole code i know literately minimum about c++ as I started learning yesturday so is it a lot of work to do it?

Comment: @user1308252 well just replace `system("copy GameMenu.res C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\"login"\\counter-strike source\\cstrike\\resource\\GameMenu.res");` by the three lines I gave you.

Comment: and i tryed to vote up but it says i need 15 reputation but im only on 1

Comment: @user1308252 You have to make sure it works before you vote up anyway ;)

Comment: it now compiles and it works but when i input the username and all it comes up with the message "The syntax of the command is incorect"

Comment: Take a look at my comment up above on the main question. Your path has spaces, and thus it needs to be enclosed in `"`. Without the `"`, it interprets it as multiple command line arguments.

Comment: I think its the command you sent me as it comes up after it says "Your files are being copied"

Comment: @crashmstr you mean it should have underscores instead of spaces or what?

Comment: If you were to type the command into the command prompt, the copy would not do what you think it does. You would need to use `copy GameMenu.res "C:\Program Files (x86)\..."`. So just like you double up the back-slash, `"` becomes `\"`.

Comment: @crashmstr I know what you mean and I know they have steam installed as its for a steam Counter Strike clan I'm in.